# Ignore own / specified file when debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to ignore own or specified files or folders when stepping in the debug tool ? So it will not go into library and such.

Edit: This question is about Visual studio CODE, not standard VS.

Comment: Can you clarify: You want to set breakpoints in certain files/folders, but then have it ignore those breakpoints without disabling them?

Comment: No, I want to set breakpoints in my own created code files, and have the debug steps ignore the library files such as the ones in node_modules. This options  exists in standard VisualStudio and is called "Just My Code" i think

Answer (score 1):

We have already a feature request for this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3215

Comment: shouldn't I open a suggestion in feature request in uservoice instead ?

Answer (score 0):

**March 2016** - This is not available in VS Code right now

Its an excellent [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new).